# VS2012 Asp.net. Crystal Report Viewer. No Tool Bar

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Development machine OS Winserver 2008 R2.

Attempting to hang an external report written in Crystal X1.

The 'Business decisions' toolbar is not displayed at the top of the CRV. There is a 'find' tab and 'page 1 1+ ' tab. Attempting to use these or the group tree sidebar drill down brings a javascript error

```
{if(!G||G.cons!=="bobj.crv.newReportAlbum"){return }for(var D=0,A=G.children.length;D<A;D++)
```

The A=G.children.length being the errored instruction.
expanding out 'G' with the Intellisense debugger shows 'children is undefined'

In VS2010 the toolbar is there  and the same report is well behaved (Page navigation works etc).

I altered the VS2012 references to point at the Crystal Assemblies used by VS2010.
VS2012 now sort of works. The toolbar is there and functions correctly  but its icons are missing.

Should I carry on down this path, or am I just attempting to bypass a fixable problem? 
Has anybody else used the VS2012 CRV OK sitting on top of a 64 bit OS?

Re-Installed the SAP CRforVS_13_0_5.exe just in case but no change.
Just now installed CRforVS_13_0_7.exe No Change.

Comment: Have you tried editing the report in VS2012? Basically just open it and then save it. Then run it and see what happens. I have not come across the problem that the toolbar is not there, usually it's just the icons for the buttons that are not displaying.

Comment: Hi, Just tried that. No Change.

Comment: Hmm...I've been doing some more reading (since I don't have VS2012 but love the challenge of troubleshooting) and the guys on the SAP forum have some interesting things to say. According to them, you should uninstall your version of CR for VS, install VS2012 and then install the appropriate version of CR for VS. See here [link]http://scn.sap.com/thread/3303855 for one post that goes through the troubleshooting process. I know it's not what one wants to do, but I think giving an uninstall/reinstall a shot may be in order.

Comment: Hi Chris,Can't see myself getting clear to re-install VS2012 with a number of projects on the go. The crystal report was a good way to show data in one of the projects but I can just as easily display the Data in say a table then allow the user to save as a file may be a PDF. So I think I'll cut my losses. Thanks for your efforts on this one. regards

Comment: I hear ya. Bummer it didn't work out but maybe on the next version of CR for VS from SAP the problem may get fixed. Cheers!